# estimator : string or callable that maps vector -> scalar

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am reading the documentation of `seaborn.barplot` and I read the following.

```
estimator : string or callable that maps vector -> scalar, optional
Statistical function to estimate within each categorical bin.
```

I could not understand what `callable that maps vector -> scalar` means. What does this statement convey?

When I passed estimator = 'mean', I got this error.

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

What should we pass as a string?

Comment: If a string is not working for you you probably need to update your seaborn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable means a function. Named function or lambda function. A function that takes a vector as argument and returns a scalar. Function are ["first class citizens"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) in Python so can be passed as argument and generally treated as any other object.

See example [here](https://www.educba.com/seaborn-barplot/):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
penguin_data = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
f = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
fig = sns.barplot(x="species", y="body_mass_g", palette = "flare",
estimator = np.mean, data=penguin_data)
```